# Pythonic Way To Call A Class Function If I have A List of Instances

Tags: class, python

So I have a list containing a number of instances of a class.

As time moves forward, I would like, at each step, to call the `run` method of the class.

So far, I have what's below. But is there a better or more Pythonic way of achieving the `for c in objs:` block?

Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class the_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num=1
    def run(self):
        self.num+=1

def main():
    objs=[]
    objs.append(the_class())
    objs.append(the_class())
    objs.append(the_class())

    for t in range(10):
        for c in objs:
            c.run()

    print objs[0].num

main()
```

Comment: General practice in for loops is to use `xrange` in lieu of `range` in more modern versions of Python; `range` is depracated.

Comment: @lukecampbell "more modern"? In more modern versions of python (3.x), ``xrange()`` doesn't exist and ``range()`` provides a generator rather than a list. In *older* versions, (2.x), yes, use ``xrange()``.

Comment: I didn't know python3 got rid of `xrange` but yes in Python 2.x was where my experience comes from and my recommendation was directed.

Comment: That's fine, your edited comment is less misleading, but I would take care when talking about modernity when referring to a previous version of anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, what you have is perfectly reasonable and Pythonic.

The list comprehension syntax:

```
[c.run() for c in objs]
```

Saves you one line, but using list comprehensions for side effects is generally considered bad style.

Comment: I actually have heard that its not usually appropriate to use a list comp just for the side effects of calling the methods

Comment: That's correct. List comprehensions are basically a functional programming construct.

Comment: If you want to one-liner it, and it returns `None`, use `any(c.run() for c in obj)`, which doesn't accumulate results.

Comment: Seriously, if you want to one-liner it for the sake of one-linering it, take up Code Golf and leave actual programming to the grown-ups.

Comment: `any` on a generator expression can be faster than a normal `for` loop, so there is a legitimate reason to use it, if it's somewhere a micro-optimization could actually help.

Comment: If the runtime of the run() function is non-trivial, the loop time will be swamped. If the runtime of the run() function is trivial, the total runtime of the loop is trivial, unless the size of the collection is enormous, in which case perhaps Python isn't the best choice of language. Using anything other than a straightforward loop here for the sake of performance is premature optimization.

Comment: "if it's somewhere a micro-optimization could actually help." Nothing premature about that. And I'm not the one who included a one-liner in an answer that didn't need one -- I just told you ___if___ you're going to use a one-liner, do it right. Also, when you reply to someone in a comment on a post that isn't theirs, you need to include "@username" so they get notified.

Comment: @RussellBorogove you're correct that removing the loop is pretty much a trivial amount of optimization.  If the run method isn't very expensive, it is of no use to remove the loop.  if the run method is very expensive, you only gain from removing the loop if it is parallelized (see my answer).  In all other cases, I completely agree with you and Lattyware that a loop is probably the best practice here.

Comment: @agf - I only included the one-liner to dismiss it as bad form.

Answer (score 6):

No, what you have is perfectly fine.

Using a list comprehension or map here would make your code less clear and harder to read. I would **strongly recommend against doing either**.

A list comprehension is designed to create a list. Where you want to make a loop, use a loop.

Even if you did need to optimise this (and it's highly unlikely that using a list comp or map would be an effective optimisation anyway) then do it when you have proof it's a bottleneck. Readability comes first, optimise only where you have to.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the `map` builtin function which does basically the same thing as the list comprehension:

```
map(lambda x:x.run(),objs)
```

but most consider list comprehensions to be more "pythonic".  Additionally, any reservations people have about using list comprehensions for side-effects can probably be applied to `map` as well.  The only reason I bring it up is because the `multiprocessing` module has a `Pool` class which has a map method to do the computation in parallel, and works basically the same as the builtin `map` ( http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html ).  If the run method takes a while to complete, and each one is independent of the others, it might be worthwhile.

**EDIT**

As stated in the comments, you can do this faster (removing the `lambda`) using the operator module.  However, the point is (and remains) that you can use `map` or `multiprocessing.Pool.map` almost interchangeably and pick up a performance boost in a lot of applications with the latter.

Comment: @agf, Thanks.  That's one optimization that I've seen around a number of times and can never seem to remember.  I'll edit.

Comment: Ya this has some overhead with the lambda

Comment: If you're going to use `operator.itemgetter('run')` for the sake of performance, just write in a lower-level language to begin with.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Thats an odd comment.

Comment: @RussellBorogove That's ridiculous. You can save money / time with optimizations and still keep the efficiency of a high level language.

Comment: Why would you ever do this? This is really unclear and hard to read. The way it was stated in the question is by far preferable.

Comment: @Lattyware -- I use map all the time, even with lambda functions (I personally perfer it to list comprehensions, though I know most disagree with me here).  The point of this was not to make some obscure, difficult to read `map` call (which I guess I've done), but to point out that the same machinery can be applied using the `multiprocessing` module to make the code go faster if that is desired.

Comment: @agf, I looked at itemgetter and honestly, I don't completely understand it at a quick glance.  Shouldn't I be using `operator.methodgetter` instead?

Comment: @mgilson My bad. It's `attrgetter` or `methodcaller` not `itemgetter`.

Comment: @agf, Yes, I had just settled on `attrgetter` myself.  Thanks.

Comment: The whole point of itemgetter and the like is to do it on the C side of code as opposed to a lambda that keeps getting called on the python side which just wraps around your method call. Also, the multiprocessor map works the same way in that it will return the results of the calls. So, ideally you are running it to get results.

Comment: Thanks, @mgilson, I didn't know about the multiprocessing map, and it may yet prove useful to me :-)

Comment: @jdi --A simple test shows that even if the list item gets changed in multiprocessing.Pool.map, that change doesn't make it's way back to the main process (good to know).  Of course, this can easily be worked around by having the function return the changed object ... My point is the same that it is good to know how map works if only to use the parallel version in the standard library when appropriate for the application.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3, you cannot simply use map, as you have to deal with it being a generator.

```
def exhaust(gen):
    for _ in gen: pass

# Using map
exhaust(map(lambda x: x.run(), c))

# Using generator comprehension (better)
exhaust(x.run() for x in c)
```

Alternatively, you could create a dummy function, and use the `*` operator:

```
def nop(*args): pass
nop(*(x.run() for x in c))
```

As others have pointed out, none of these are very pretty to read.  Stick to what you have, so that people can read it.

EDIT: Improved exhaust function, thanks wim.

Comment: Catching the `StopIteration` thrown by a generator in order to break out of a `while True:` loop?!  That's crazy.  You know you can replace the whole construct with `for g in gen: pass`

Comment: @wim thanks, some old code I had in there, and I was just trying to write it fast.  Also, `next(gen)` sounds cool. :P

Comment: This is the same solution, except with extra cruft - you are just moving the loop to a different segment of code. As a side not, if you want to consume an entire iterable, check the [`consume()` itertools recipe](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) which is the most efficient way to do this.